# can't install gem on managed server 1und1

Tags: ruby, rubygems

> gem install net-http-digest_auth
>   /kunden/homepages/44/d374119480/htdocs/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/syck.rb:82:in `<module:Syck>': uninitialized constant Syck::DefaultResolver (NameError)
>       from /kunden/homepages/44/d374119480/htdocs/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/syck.rb:80:in`'
>       from :29:in `require'
>       from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in`require'
>       from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/yaml/syck.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
>       from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in`require'
>       from :29:in `require'
>       from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/yaml.rb:11:in`'
>       from :29:in `require'
>       from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in`require'
>       from /kunden/homepages/44/d374119480/htdocs/executable/ruby/lib/rubygems/config_file.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
>       from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in`require'
>       from :29:in `require'
>       from /kunden/homepages/44/d374119480/htdocs/executable/ruby/lib/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:8:in`'
>       from :29:in `require'
>       from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in`require'
>       from /kunden/homepages/44/d374119480/htdocs/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/gem:13:in `'

Anytime I try to start gem I get the quoted error on my server. I used rvm to install ruby 1.9.2, I tried to install it by myself first though. I would appreciate any hint! (I have no root rights).

For anybody else who is in the early stage as i am i recommend http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book

> ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tutorial:
>     system:
>       uname:       "Linux icpu890 2.6.28.8-20101130b-iscsi-ntacker-fasync-mremap-amd-sec6-grsec #1 SMP Tue Nov 30 18:27:29 CET 2010 i686 GNU/Linux"
>       bash:        "/bin/bash => GNU bash, version 4.1.5(1)-release (i486-pc-linux-gnu)"
>       zsh:         "/usr/bin/zsh => zsh 4.3.2 (i686-pc-linux-gnu)"
>     rvm:
>       version:      "rvm 1.6.25 by Wayne E. Seguin (wayneeseguin@gmail.com) [https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/]"
>     ruby:
>       interpreter:  "ruby"
>       version:      "1.9.2p290"
>       date:         "2011-07-09"
>       platform:     "i686-linux"
>       patchlevel:   "2011-07-09 revision 32553"
>       full_version: "ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09 revision 32553) [i686-linux]"
>     homes:
>       gem:          "/kunden/homepages/44/d374119480/htdocs/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tutorial"
>       ruby:         "/kunden/homepages/44/d374119480/htdocs/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290"
>     binaries:
>       ruby:         "/kunden/homepages/44/d374119480/htdocs/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby"
>       irb:          "/kunden/homepages/44/d374119480/htdocs/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/irb"
>       gem:          "/kunden/homepages/44/d374119480/htdocs/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/gem"
>       rake:         "/kunden/homepages/44/d374119480/htdocs/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/rake"
>     environment:
>       PATH:         "/kunden/homepages/44/d374119480/htdocs/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tutorial/bin:/kunden/homepages/44/d374119480/htdocs/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/bin:/kunden/homepages/44/d374119480/htdocs/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin:/kunden/homepages/44/d374119480/htdocs/.rvm/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin:/bin:/usr/local/msql/bin:/usr/games:."
>       GEM_HOME:     "/kunden/homepages/44/d374119480/htdocs/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tutorial"
>       GEM_PATH:     "/kunden/homepages/44/d374119480/htdocs/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tutorial:/kunden/homepages/44/d374119480/htdocs/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global"
>       MY_RUBY_HOME: "/kunden/homepages/44/d374119480/htdocs/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290"
>       IRBRC:        "/kunden/homepages/44/d374119480/htdocs/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/.irbrc"
>       RUBYOPT:      ""
>       gemset:       "rails3tutorial"

Thank you for your answer @mrampton! I quoted rvm above. gem install fcgi doesn't work as well (ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
    Permission denied - /kunden/homepages/17/d123456789)

I fear i messed up my server with this code: http://schalanda.name/static/rails_on_rtr/rails_on_rtr.html#Quickstart

which gem doesnt work as well. It simply gives me no info (also no error).

other gems that I have tried don't work as well:

> (uiserver):u64138477:~ > gem install copland
>   Fetching: copland-1.0.0.gem (100%)
>   ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
>       Permission denied - /kunden/homepages/17/d123456789
>   (uiserver):u64138477:~ > gem install formtastic
>   Fetching: activesupport-3.0.9.gem (100%)
>   ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
>       Permission denied - /kunden/homepages/17/d123456789

Answer (score 1):

What does "rvm info" say?  Are other gems able to install?

Upon installing rvm you should have gem installed and ready for use by default -- without the need to use sudo for interacting with it.

Comment: I can only assume you are lacking permissions for the folder "/kunden/homepages/17/d123456789".  Perhaps you made an errant chmod|chown?